# How to create Bootstrap-like shorthand props for React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

What is the best way to achieve this behavior along with React + TypeScript?

```js
import { Button, Card } from 'src/components';

const Page = () => (
  <div>
    <Card mx3 p3 flex justifyContentEnd>
      /* Card content */
    </Card>
    <Button my2 mx3>
      Login
    </Button>
  </div>
);
```

For instance, `mx3` will add 16px margin horizontally, `my2` will add 8px margin vertically, etc., similar to how the Bootstrap framework uses classes to apply utility styles easily.

I have looked through a few component libraries with this sort of behavior in order to find a suitable solution; however, I find most do not have strong typing support. Examples are RNUILib, NativeBase, Magnus UI, etc.

Comment: Why not use a class instead?

Comment: @Konrad For the `<Button />` and `<Card />` components?

Comment: Yes, `className="mx3 p3 flex justifyContentEnd"` and create classes in css

Comment: These mx3, p3, flex, justifyContentEnd all are mapped to true boolean value and you can read it inside the Card as usual and add logic for that

Comment: @Konrad Yes, you could do that, however, I failed to mention in the question, I am using React Native. We usually only have a `styles` prop to pass styles (i.e., no class names).

Comment: Take a look at this https://www.nativewind.dev/ - using a single prop is easier than declaring types for a thousand

Comment: @Konrad Interesting, I will take a look. My only complaint would be the typing support for that className prop; however, I understand that even Bootstrap with plain React does not offer such type support.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Yes, I know the props as accessible within the `<Button />` and `<Card />` components; however, I am more interested in how we would convert these boolean props to styles, and furthermore, how would we extract this logic so many components can reuse the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your props like that:

```
const styles = ['mx3', 'p3', 'flex'] as const

type Styles = Record<typeof styles[number], boolean>;
```

Then use them like this:

```
type CardProps = Styles & {
  other: 'props here'
}
```

Now, this should work:

```
<Card mx3 p3 flex />
```

You can get applied props like this:

```
const values = Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) => value ? key : null).filter(Boolean)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [source code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/Button.tsx#L96) of react-bootstrap, they have mapped the boolean to some CSS class using a util function of [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package. You can do the same:

```
...
...
        <Component
          {...buttonProps}
          {...props}
          ref={ref}
          className={classNames(
            className,
            prefix,
            active && 'active',
            variant && `${prefix}-${variant}`,
            size && `${prefix}-${size}`,
            props.href && props.disabled && 'disabled',
          )}
        />
...
...
```